# Error importing module

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm developing an application using django 1.2 on Google-app-engine (SDK 1.7.5). When I test the application locally using the dev_appserver it works, and it works also when I upload it on Google's servers. The problem is that the application doesn't work if I try with a newer SDK (I tried version 1.8.0) locally.
This is the error reported:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware
>   authentication.middleware: "No module named authentication.models"

In MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES I import:

> ```
> 'authentication.middleware.AccessFilterMiddleware'
> ```

that I've developed. The problem is that inside that module I import "models" that is in the root directory (the folder in which is contained the authentication package), but it tries to search it inside authentication package. I've also tried to use

```
import .. models
```

but in that case the error thrown is:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Thank you

Comment: Does "from parent_directory_module import models" work? Is this "parent directory" an actual python module (does it have __init__.py) and is it available in the python path?

Comment: Yes, I tried from parent_directory import models and that works. But I thought it was bad practice to use the project name in import, and I can not understand why the import checks only authentication.models and does not try its parent directory that is in path. Furthermore with the previous version of the SDK it works.

Comment: It's not a bad practice, since your inner app is obviously dependent to the top level app anyway. The case is "models" alone is not in the python path, it is the "root_module" being in path and therefore "root_module.models" is a valid module.

Comment: I would also add that not using the latest version of the SDK (1.8.2) is a bad idea.